# How to drop constraint in trigger in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing a database for practical purposes which involves some triggers and constraints for the moment.

One of my triggers must set a column value to 0 before deleting a speciffied row , but the deletion cannot work with the constraint on ... so I decided that `BEFORE DELETE` I remove the constraint then after I update my column value from the other table I will `ADD` it again using my 2nd trigger.

However I can get it to work :

```
ALTER TABLE teams ADD CONSTRAINT teams_to_trainer FOREIGN KEY (coda)
REFERENCES trainer(coda);

--insert values
--...

--Procedure in which I execute the alter table commands

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE constraint_operation (p_hardcod IN VARCHAR2)
IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
resource_busy EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(resource_busy,-54);
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_hardcod;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN resource_busy
  THEN
  DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5);
 COMMIT;
END;
/

--My Two Triggers

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_trainer

  BEFORE DELETE
  ON trainer
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  constraint_operation('ALTER TABLE teams DROP CONSTRAINT teams_to_trainer');
  UPDATE teams SET coda = 0 WHERE :old.coda = coda;

END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_trainer_add_constraint
  AFTER DELETE
  ON trainer
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  constraint_operation('ALTER TABLE teams ADD CONSTRAINT teams_to_trainer 
                        FOREIGN KEY (coda)REFERENCES trainer(coda)');
END;
/
```

And when calling :

```
DELETE FROM trainer WHERE coda = 14;
```

I get this :

> SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER.TEAMS_TO_TRAINER)
>   violated - parent key not found
>   02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
>   *Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
>   *Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

I can't seem to find the problem , I thought calling the procedure will remove the constraint.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are having to disable constraints to get DML to work, then there is something seriously wrong with your design, and you should re-think it.

Comment: You can disable constraints and have less churn but the whole idea needs a rethink.  With your code that sleeps when the row is busy you just put off finalizing the transaction.  This will not scale.  Tell us with table descriptions what you need to do.

Comment: why not drop constrains altogether, and in `before insert` trigger check if foreign key exists, else raise exception.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to raise an exception because in my design deleting that row is a normal behaviour. So I'm trying to delete a trainer which is like a coach in a footbal team. Then I update the value in the team where that coach was , that is why I need a foreign key in trainer.  But creating the constraint will make the trainer a child. I want to delete the trainer but I want the team to be still.

Comment: To amplify what others have said, dropping or disabling a constraint, and then re-enabling it would be a performance nightmare.  If you have thousands of rows of data, the enabling of the constraint will have to re-check every single row to ensure the constraint is valid.  And if not, how will your code respond to _that_?

Comment: Why are you updating with zero (which has no matching trainer, hence the error) instead of null, to indicate there is no trainer associated with the team? That seems safer than having to add a dummy trainer. You don't even need a trigger, just make the constraint `on delete set null`.

Comment: Yes , indeed I was making this all wrong , I have modified now ; it was a mistake at my constrains design. As with the performance , yes it's not a good idea whatever rubbish was I doing. Thank you all for pointing in the right direction , I will mark Patrick's answer for accepted however because it worked on the question's context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating a foreign key column in TEAMS to a value that doesn't exist in the referenced primary key in TRAINER.

If the FK constraint is required, a simple fix would be to add a default/dummy row in TRAINER where the value in CODA is 0.